# Read data from a flat file (Datastore) in an ODI procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying read a file from a PL/SQL procedure but I am geting ORA-00942 Table or view does not exist error.

```
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 21, Sql = 
SELECT UBIC_ID FROM LIST_UBICS

, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I have a file with an id per line. This file is called list_ubics.csv. I have a File model and a datastore pointing to the file called LIST_UBIC with the UBIC_ID Field.

I created a Task in a new Procedure with this SQL:
`SELECT UBIC_ID From LIST_UBICS`

**LIST_UBICS** is my datastore I don't have any table with these name.

I want read these file and make some processing for each line but I don't see any way in the docs to read a text file that works for me.

How can I read this file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

An ODI Procedure written in PL/SQL (Oracle Technology) will be pushed down on the database. The database executing doesn't know about the File Datastore and can not execute SQL statement against it.

If the goal is to load the file with ODI it can be done using an interface (11g) or a mapping (12c) with **LKM File to SQL**. That will copy the content of the file into a table in the database and any SQL statement can then be executed against it.

Alternatively, it is possible to create a directory in the database, land the file there and create an **external table** on top of it. Queries can be used on external table but not DML operations. More information here : https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i

Comment: The problem with the Mapping (I am using 12c) Is that I have to search for each one of these ids in the files in a big view (millions of register) if this ID exist and if exists make my insert in target table. This "one to one" check if exist is the thing that I can't make in the mapping and the execution is always getting stucked if I only put a Join using the file id and the view id.

Comment: The join shouldn't be an issue for a few million rows. Just make sure that you have indexes on the ID attributes in both tables. And check that the stats are correctly gathered. If that doesn't work the external table alternative I suggested above is still an option.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out last week that there is one more solution and probably the best!
The solution is written [here-part-1](http://odiexperts.com/how-to-refresh-odi-variables-from-file-part-1-just-one-value/) and [here-part-2](http://odiexperts.com/how-to-refresh-odi-variables-from-file-part-2-getting-all-lines-once-at-time/) and if you follow the steps exactly, it will work (I implemented it).

Anyway, I will summarize the main idea and steps.

We can use a variable into a package. There is a code (see code at the end) that reads a column from the given file. Making a for statement in the package, will help us read every row, by changing the value of "CRFILE_FIRST_ROW" variable from the code below, with a sequential number starting with 1 (

So, everything is easy as above. Besides the "CRFILE_FIRST_ROW", there are more variable that can be changed, like: CRFILE_FORMAT=D (format:decimal), CRFILE_SEP_FIELD=0x0009 (hexadecimal fileformat) and so on.

Also, as you can see in the original posts (above links), you can generate your view code; you don't need to copy paste from below.

View code:

```
select  TES.C1  C1
from    location_of_file/objects_to_import.txt TES
/*$$SNPS_START_KEYSNP$CRDWG_TABLESNP$CRTABLE_NAME=TESTSNP$CRLOAD_FILE=location_of_file/objects_to_import.txtSNP$CRFILE_FORMAT=DSNP$CRFILE_SEP_FIELD=0x0009SNP$CRFILE_SEP_LINE=0x000ASNP$CRFILE_FIRST_ROW=#UTILS.IMPORT_OBJ_READ_INCRSNP$CRFILE_ENC_FIELD=SNP$CRFILE_DEC_SEP=SNP$CRSNP$CRDWG_COLSNP$CRCOL_NAME=C1SNP$CRTYPE_NAME=STRINGSNP$CRORDER=1SNP$CRLENGTH=50SNP$CRPRECISION=50SNP$CRACTION_ON_ERROR=NULLSNP$CR$$SNPS_END_KEY*/
```